# PDOException Laravel Password expiry

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I had a strange encouter with my with my Laravel Homestead setup run locally on my mac. I just wanted to get data from my database via my api and got this message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1862] Your password has expired. To log in you must
>   change it using a client that supports expired passwords.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your mysql password has expired. You can use the command line to change it. `mysql -u yourusername -p`, and it should prompt you.

Comment: I logged into homestead ssh. Typed what you said with the current password and it just starts without asking